# Is there any way to fix "name 'end' is not defined?"

Tags: python-3.x

I have this line of code:

```
arr_thres = sorted(x_train)
    for i in range(len(arr_thres)):
        if i != end:
            thres = (arr_thres[i] + arr_thres[i+1])/2
            arr_gain.append((thres, gainDisc(arr_tbl[j], col, result, thres)))
            
    arr_max = max(arr_gain,key=lambda x: x[1])
    arr_batas.append(arr_max[0])

    subtresult = get_subtables_disc(arr_tbl[j], col, arr_max[0])
```

but whenever I try to run it, I always get this error warning:

```
NameError: name 'end' is not defined
```

Comment: Did u define the value in the variable `end`

Comment: Did you mean `'end'`?

Answer (score 1):

"end" is a variable name, one you have not defined. For the if statement to check if it is the last element to be iterated use:

```
if i == len(arr_thres) - 1:
```